# Rails 'Method not found' in form_for f.text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added a new column using following command:

```
rails g migration AddMatrixPositionToAnswer matrix_position:integer
```

then ran the command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now if I write the following code to my view, I get Method not found

```
<%= f.number_field :matrix_position, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

error is:

[image: Method not found]

**Update:**

Migration file: 
[image]

Database Schema: 
[image]

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@answer) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :matrix_position %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :matrix_position %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :value, :class => 'form-control', :Placeholder => 'Any value (e.g. M (Male), F (Female), United States (US))' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :question_id %>

  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit(:value => ' Save', :class => 'fa btn btn-success' ) %>
<hr />

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Interestingly, <%= f.label :matrix_position %> works. But <%= f.text_field :matrix_position %> doesn't work.

Comment: Open up the actual add_matrix_position_to_answer_xxxxxx.rb migration file and post the contents.

Comment: Post the schema and form view, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a `TYPO` in your database table's column. See carefully:
`martix_position` in the database. But, you are specifying `matrix_position` in the `f.text_field`, that's why it's failing :)

So, either change database column to `matrix_position` with another migration. Or, use: `f.text_field :martix_position` in the form, your choice :-)

Comment: I tried in different new project. Everything works fine in other project. Except this one.

Comment: Hey, I found the problem. Its a TYPO in your database table's column. You mistyped it `martix_position` instead of `matrix_position`. I have updated my answer. Hope this works now :-)